# Acts as votable vote_registered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I have implemented acts as votable in my Rails app and all going well.

According to it's git: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable it says there is a method called vote_registered? to check if the vote was valid if the user has already voted on it previously.

It says:

To check if a vote counted, or registered, use vote_registered? on your model after voting. For example:

@hat.liked_by @user

@hat.vote_registered? # => true

I just wanted some help trying to implement it.

Thanks.

I have tried this in my articles_controller but getting errors from the Action controller like Missing template articles/upvote, application/upvote with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}

```
def upvote
@article.upvote_by current_user
if @article.vote_registered?
  flash[:success] = "Successfully liked"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
    format.json { render json: { count: @article.get_upvotes.size } }
  end
else
  flash[:danger] = "You have already liked this"
end
  end
```

From my article controller with the current working voting:

```
 def upvote
    @article.upvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully liked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.get_upvotes.size } }
    end
  end
  def downvote
    @article.downvote_by current_user
    flash[:success] = "Successfully disliked"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @article.get_downvotes.size } }
    end
  end
```

Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc)}
end
```

From webpage when voting:

```
<h1 class="article-detail-title"><%= @article.title %></h1>
  <div class="votes" id="likes-dislikes">
      <hr>
    <%= link_to like_article_path(@article), method: :put, class: 'voting' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <%= @article.get_upvotes.size %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to dislike_article_path(@article), method: :put, class: 'voting' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
        <%= @article.get_downvotes.size %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="article-date">
      <%= @article.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions", :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks"}
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root to: 'articles#index'
  resources :articles do
    member do
      put "like", to: "articles#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "articles#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I was close, just needed to push the user back to the existing page.

```
def upvote
    @article.upvote_by current_user
    if @article.vote_registered?
      flash[:success] = "Successfully liked"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { count: @article.get_upvotes.size } }
      end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "You have already liked this"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end
  def downvote
    @article.downvote_by current_user
    if @article.vote_registered?
      flash[:success] = "Successfully disliked"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render json: { count: @article.get_downvotes.size } }
     end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "You have already disliked this"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
      end
    end
  end
```